# Is it possible to install only the docker cli and not the daemon

Tags: docker

I want to have docker CLI to connect to remote daemon but do I need to install the whole engine including daemon on the local machine?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to install Docker in Linux, then in the newest [1.12.0 release](https://github.com/docker/docker/releases/tag/v1.12.0), Docker daemon and Docker client are in separate binary files.

This has been mentioned in release log:

> Split the binary into two: docker (client) and dockerd (daemon) #[20639](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/20639)

If you are installing Docker in Mac, then Mac OS binary is client-only: [resource](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/binaries/#/get-the-mac-os-x-binary)

Comment: Can docker daemon(remote machine) and docker client(local machine) be  different version?

Answer (score 130):

First, download and unzip/untar the release for your system. Here are x86_64 binaries for [mac](https://download.docker.com/mac/static/stable/x86_64/), [linux](https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/), [windows](https://download.docker.com/win/static/stable/x86_64/).

After expanding the archive, you can find the docker CLI executable at `./docker/docker` - move that file into your path, and you're done.

If you're specifically looking to install the docker CLI into a docker image, here's my Dockerfile command to do so:

```
ENV DOCKERVERSION=18.03.1-ce
RUN curl -fsSLO https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/docker-${DOCKERVERSION}.tgz \
  && tar xzvf docker-${DOCKERVERSION}.tgz --strip 1 \
                 -C /usr/local/bin docker/docker \
  && rm docker-${DOCKERVERSION}.tgz
```

h/t to [this comment](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/15360#issuecomment-255171243)

Comment: You can extract a single file from a *.tar archive by just specifying the path to the file you want to extract. This way you don't have to move files around. To directly extract the `docker` binary use `tar xzvf docker-${DOCKERVERSION}.tgz --strip=1 -C /usr/local/bin docker/docker` where `strip=1` strips the first path component (the docker folder) and effectively flattens the extracted file. See https://superuser.com/questions/71846/tar-extract-discarding-directory-structure for further details.

Comment: how to solve this: `Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock` ?

Comment: @IvanAracki - that means the CLI cannot communicate with the daemon. There are many reasons why this could be. If you can't figure it out, I'd recommend asking it as a question (with a full description of your environment).

Comment: I solved permission problem with changing ownership of mounted docker.sock with `docker exec -it -u root jenkins-docker chown jenkins /var/run/docker.sock`

Answer (score 23):

Adding to the approach from Aaron, if you're building your own image, you can now just use multi-stage builds to copy over the `docker` binary from an existing external image, e.g.:

```
COPY --from=docker:dind /usr/local/bin/docker /usr/local/bin/
```

This pulls the `docker` binary from the public
`docker:dind` image [on Dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker).

See: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/.

Comment: For those like me who didn't get this at first glance, `docker:dind` refers to [this image on Dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker). It happens to have the `docker` client at `/usr/local/bin/docker`.

Comment: Thanks @Ritchie, updated the answer with some clarification! :)

Comment: **Note** if you are getting `failed to copy file: Container ID 166535 cannot be mapped to a host ID`, in a multi-stage build, you need to chown /usr/local/bin/docker in the source, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64557582/1735931)

Comment: Hmm, running into errors when I try to use this approach to build a BuildKit-based image: `the --mount option requires BuildKit. Refer to https://docs.docker.com/go/buildkit/ to learn how to build images with BuildKit enabled`. Will see if it works better with the `docker-ce-cli` package from https://download.docker.com...

Comment: Yep, using `docker-ce-cli` package by following the instructions at https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/ worked much better for me.

Answer (score 11):

On Windows, you can install the CLI by itself using [chocolatey package manager](https://chocolatey.org/packages/docker-cli).

Once you have chocolatey loaded you can run this from an admin command prompt:

```
choco install /y docker-cli
```

This seems to be much more up-to-date than the Windows link provided by Aaron, for some reason.  (v19 instead of v17, as of Jan 2020)

Comment: It is more up-to-date because it is taken from here: https://github.com/StefanScherer/docker-cli-builder/releases

Comment: This is the best answer for Windows!

Comment: Why should I have to having something called 'chocolately' on my system just to download and install a CLI tool?  Is there not an MSI or executable installer?

Answer (score 10):

You can (like the other answer suggests) download it direct from Docker:

```
docker_url=https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64
docker_version=18.03.1-ce
curl -fsSL $docker_url/docker-$docker_version.tgz | \
tar zxvf - --strip 1 -C /usr/bin docker/docker
```

The difference from the other answer is that there is no intermediate tar file. I use this in a Dockerfile RUN layer.

Comment: I used something similar to this and works fine, I needed root to do: `docker exec -it -u root id-docker-container /bin/bash`

Answer (score 8):

If you are installing docker from the offical package repositories as described in [these instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/), you can simply install the `docker-ce-cli` package and omit the installation of `docker-ce` and `containerd.io`.

Full installation sequence (for Ubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    gnupg \
    lsb-release

curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg

echo \
  "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
  $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null

sudo apt-get update

# Here is the part that is different
sudo apt-get install docker-ce-cli
```

Comment: Best answer for package maintainability.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Windows, you can download an up-to-date build of Docker CLI from here:

[StefanScherer/docker-cli-builder](https://github.com/StefanScherer/docker-cli-builder/releases)

And point to a remote Docker Daemon by setting `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable:

```
$env:DOCKER_HOST = 'tcp://X.X.X.X:2375'
```

Please note that, in order for this to work, the Docker Daemon must be configured to expose its API over TCP. This can be done in `daemon.json` file:

```
{
    "hosts": ["unix:///var/run/docker.sock", "tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"]
}
```

Comment: With newer versions of docker it is easier and more secure to use ssh to connect to the remote docker. No change is needed on the server at all other then setting up ssh (which is likely done for other reasons anyway) and then on the client set `DOCKER_HOST` to `ssh://<userid>@<server ip or name>`.  Using tcp the way you describe here leaves the system very open to exploits.

Answer (score 3):

For Ubuntu:

```
apt-get update
apt-get download docker.io
dpkg --fsys-tarfile docker.io_*.deb | tar xOf - ./usr/bin/docker > ./docker-cli
chmod +x ./docker-cli
rm docker.io_*.deb
shopt -s expand_aliases  # alias are not expanded in non-interactive mode (e.g. gitlab ci)
alias docker=$PWD/docker-cli
```

Useful in case you are working with remote docker daemon (env `DOCKER_HOST`).

Answer (score 2):

If you want docker and docker-compose CLIs without daemon you can install them as python packages which also installs executables:

```
python pip install docker docker-compose
```

and set the environment variable DOCKER_HOST i.e `DOCKER_HOST = SSH://user@host`

Answer (score 2):

In Windows better use winget command:

```
winget install Docker.DockerCLI
```