# Docker not found when building docker image using Docker Jenkins container pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins running as a docker container, now I want to build a Docker image using pipeline, but Jenkins container always tells Docker not found.

```
[simple-tdd-pipeline] Running shell script
+ docker build -t simple-tdd .
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/simple-tdd-pipeline@tmp/durable-
ebc35179/script.sh: 2: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/simple-tdd-
pipeline@tmp/durable-ebc35179/script.sh: docker: not found
```

Here is how I run my Jenkins image:

```
docker run --name myjenkins -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v 
/var/jenkins_home -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock 
jenkins
```

And the DockerFile of Jenkins image is:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/9f29488b77c2005bbbc5c936d47e697689f8ef6e/Dockerfile

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're missing the docker client. Install it as this in Dockerfile:

```
RUN curl -fsSLO https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-17.04.0-ce.tgz \
  && tar xzvf docker-17.04.0-ce.tgz \
  && mv docker/docker /usr/local/bin \
  && rm -r docker docker-17.04.0-ce.tgz
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43594065/1094246)

Comment: I added the above script and built the dockerfile, it failed with below error: 

    curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 16384)

Comment: I can run the command now, just changing user as root before the curl command. USER root

Comment: Yes. Or add the command before the line that redefine the user

Answer (score 23):

In your Jenkins interface go to *"Manage Jenkins/Global Tool Configuration"*

Then scroll down to Docker Installations and click *"Add Docker"*. Give it a name like *"myDocker"*

Make sure to check the box which says *"Install automatically"*. Click *"Add Installer"* and select *"Download from docker.com"*. Leave "latest" in the Docker version. Make sure you click Save.

[image]

In your Jenkinsfile add the following stage before you run any docker commands:

```
 stage('Initialize'){
        def dockerHome = tool 'myDocker'
        env.PATH = "${dockerHome}/bin:${env.PATH}"
    }
```

Comment: Does this approach require extra configuration? I've done the same thing and was able to run simple commands as `docker -v`, but when it comes to `docker build` I got `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`... Any advice?

Comment: @ChernikovP I am getting the same error. Could you solve it?

Comment: @ChernikovP, @khushboo29 you need to add `jenkins` to group `docker`, something this way: `sudo usermod -a -G docker jenkins`

Comment: It works, I had to add the code into stage>steps>scripts to work

Answer (score 14):

**Edit: May 2018**

As pointed by [Guillaume Husta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1677594/guillaume-husta), this [jpetazzo's blog article](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/) discourages this technique:

> Former versions of this post advised to `bind-mount` the docker binary from the host to the container. This is not reliable anymore, because the Docker Engine is no longer distributed as (almost) static libraries.

Docker client should be installed inside a container as described [here](https://getintodevops.com/blog/the-simple-way-to-run-docker-in-docker-for-ci). Also, `jenkins` user should be in `docker` group, so execute following:

```
$ docker exec -it -u root my-jenkins /bin/bash
# usermod -aG docker jenkins
```

and finally restart `my-jenkins` container.

**Original answer:**

You could use host's `docker engine` like in this [@Adrian Mouat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4332/adrian-mouat) blog [article](https://container-solutions.com/running-docker-in-jenkins-in-docker/).

```
 docker run -d \
   --name my-jenkins \
   -v /var/jenkins_home:~/.jenkins \
   -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
   -p 8080:8080 jenkins
```

This avoids having multiple docker engine version on host and jenkins container.

Comment: The best volume mapping is `-v /usr/local/bin:/user/bin`, otherwise will cause :`docker: Error response from daemon: Mounts denied: EOF.`

Comment: Is it still recommended ? See this note : `Former versions of this post advised to bind-mount the docker binary from the host to the container. This is not reliable anymore, because the Docker Engine is no longer distributed as (almost) static libraries.`. Source : https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/

Comment: @Guillaume Husta, you are probably right, if `Docker` uses system libraries, it *may* be unsafe. However, I'm using this binding from a `coreos` host, in a jenkins `debian` image since 1 year now in 30+ docker images... Not seen any conflict or trouble in a `docker build` process.

Comment: OK thanks for your feedback. As you said, it will depend on the context.

Comment: I think the original answer is still valid, as this way of exposing host's docker binary using volume mount is exactly what is done under Docker Build strategy by Red Hat's Openshift Container Platform v3.11 (LTS) (you can clearly see `/var/run/docker.sock` listed in Volume Mounts created by the service account), so I hope this alleviates some concerns regarding stability ;)

Answer (score 8):

The problem is in your Jenkins, it isn't capable to use the docker engine, even if you do install the docker from the plugin manager. From what I got researching there are some alternatives to workaround this issue:

**1:** Build a image using some docker image with pre-installed docker in it like provided by **getintodevops/jenkins-withdocker:lts**

**2:** Build the images from jenkins/jenkins mounting the volumes to your host then install the docker all by yourself by creating another container with same volumes and executing the bash cmd to install the docker or using [Robert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1094246/robert) suggestion

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v $HOME/.jenkins/:/var/jenkins_home 
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock jenkins/jenkins:latest
```

**or 3:** The most simple, just add the installed docker path from your host machine to be used by your jenkins container with: `-v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker`

Your docker command should look like this:

```
docker run \
--name jenkins --rm \
-u root -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 \
-v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker\
-v $HOME/.jenkins/:/var/jenkins_home 
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
jenkins/jenkins:latest
```

[Source]https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-not-found-in-jenkins-pipeline/31683

Extra option: Makes no sense if you just want to make use of a single Jenkis server but it's always possible to install a OS like Ubuntu using an image and install the jenkins .war file from there

Answer (score 2):

```sh
docker run -d \
--group-add docker \
-v $(pwd)/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
-v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker \
-p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 \
jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

Just add option `--group-add docker` when docker run.

Comment: getting this error on using the above method
`docker: Error response from daemon: Unable to find group docker.`

Answer (score 1):

This section helped me install docker inside the jenkins container: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/docker/#downloading-and-running-jenkins-in-docker. The following is mentioned in the documentation.

> The recommended Docker image to use is the Official jenkins/jenkins image (from the Docker Hub repository). This image contains the current Long-Term Support (LTS) release of Jenkins (which is production-ready). However this image doesn’t have docker CLI inside it and is not bundled with frequently used Blue Ocean plugins and features. This means that if you want to use the full power of Jenkins and Docker you may want to go through described below installation process.

Comment: Version pinning is recommended for repeatable builds. Don't blindly replace with implicit `:latest`

Comment: Noted, thanks for pointing it out. Have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add docker path i.e `-v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker` to container in volumes like

```
 docker run -d \
   --name my-jenkins \
   -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker \
   -v /var/jenkins_home:~/.jenkins \
   -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
   -p 8080:8080 jenkins
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Docker was not found in my Jenkins Server. So to fix that, we need to install docker along with Jenkins Image.

Working code:

```
1.Create one docker file named as "DockerfileJenkins"
2. Create docker-compose file for Jenkins Server.
3. Run the docker-compose file.
```

**DockerfileJenkins**:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins

USER root

# see https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/
RUN curl -L \
  "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.25.3/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" \
  -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose \
  && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

RUN curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com | sh


USER jenkins
```

**docker-compose**:

```
version: '2'
services:

  jenkins:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerfileJenkins
    hostname: jenkins
    container_name: jenkins
    restart: always
    privileged: true
    user: root
    ports:
      - 8083:8080
      - 50003:50000

    volumes:
      - ~/jenkins_data:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a docker-compose file to launch Jenkins you should add `- /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker` to the volumes.

Example:

```
version: '3'
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    restart: always
    privileged: true
    user: root
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 50000:50000
    container_name: jenkins
    volumes:
      - jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
volumes:
      jenkins_home:
```