# docker: not found when using docker command using Docker Jenkins container

Tags: docker, jenkins, jhipster

jenkins is running in a Docker container.

Docker is using in a Mac OS. So I marked out these lines in jenkins.yml:

```
    # mount docker sock and binary for docker in docker (only works on linux)
    #- /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    #- /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
```

in Jenkinsfile which is generated by JHipster and includes two tasks int he pipeline:

1. Perform the build in a Docker container
2. Analyze code with Sonar

List item

```
node {
stage('checkout') {
    checkout scm
}

docker.image('openjdk:8').inside('-u root -e MAVEN_OPTS="-Duser.home=./"') {
    stage('check java') {
        sh "java -version"
    }
```

checkout from bitbucket was successful. the pipeline stopped and got an error at docker "pull openjdk:8". Console Output is:

```
[AAAAApp] Running shell script
+ docker inspect -f . openjdk:8
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/GeneticsDB@tmp/durable-21459aca/script.sh: 
2: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/GeneticsDB@tmp/durable-21459aca/script.sh: docker: not found
[Pipeline] sh
[AAAAApp] Running shell script
+ docker pull openjdk:8
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/GeneticsDB@tmp/durable-d5590370/script.sh: 
2: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/GeneticsDB@tmp/durable-d5590370/script.sh: docker: not found
```

but this command could be run successfully in the command line, like below:

```
docker pull openjdk:8
    8: Pulling from library/openjdk
    Digest: sha256:18c9622a8dc67b608a2dd0178b4c5aebc0e2da9a656072c6e799cfc46cb96422
    Status: Image is up to date for openjdk:8
```

I know there is a similar question: [Docker not found when building docker image using Docker Jenkins container pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44850565/docker-not-found-when-building-docker-image-using-docker-jenkins-container-pipel)

But my docker is running in Mac OS.

Comment: another problem: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock.

Comment: So I try "docker exec -it ec379335d599 ls -l /var/run/docker.sock",  get "rw-rw---- 1 root root 0 Feb 10 19:16 /var/run/docker.sock". Then I tried to change the permission: "docker exec -it ec379335d599 chmod o+r /var/run/docker.sock", got an error "chmod: changing permissions of '/var/run/docker.sock': Operation not permitted"

Comment: For anyone else having this problem you need to reboot your mac and press ⌘+R when booting up. Then go into Utilities > Terminal and type the following commands:

csrutil disable
reboot 
This is a result of System Integrity Protection.

Comment: :( still not successful

Answer (score 2):

The problem actually is How to run Docker inside a container running on Docker for Mac. It is fixed by

```
brew install docker
```

and update jenkins.yml to

```
 # mount docker sock and binary for docker in docker
- /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
- /usr/local/bin/docker:/usr/local/bin/docker
```

Answer (score 0):

got an error:

```
Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (Got 
permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket 
at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get 
http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.35/info: dial unix 
/var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied). Using system 
default: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon 
socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post 
http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.35/images/create?
fromImage=openjdk&tag=8: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: 
permission denied
```

---

Solution: update the access permission of /var/run/docker.sock in docker container.

1. find the container of Jenkins: docker container ps -a
2. login the container: docker exec -it -u root ec379335d599 /bin/bash
3. upadte permission: chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock

Answer (score 0):

If your jenkins is running inside of a docker container, then I'd recommend:

1. installing docker inside that container
2. mounting the docker socket so it can run docker commands from inside the container
3. dynamically adjusting group permissions of the jenkins user in an entrypoint.sh of the jenkins container, so you don't need to change permissions of the docker socket or try to match the host group to the container group

The last part I do with an entrypoint that runs as root, runs a `groupmod` to adjust the gid of the user's group, and then drops permissions to that user with an `exec` + `gosu` which replaces pid 1 with the jenkins server running as the jenkins user. All the code needed to do this is up in the following git repo: https://github.com/sudo-bmitch/jenkins-docker