# How can I build an app and build dockerfille using node image in a Jenkinsfile?

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline

I have a working Jenkinsfile that uses node and a small Makefile to build a small static web site.

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'node'
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        script {
          sh 'make'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But then I wanted to publish the static web site as a self-contained Docker image so that I could deploy it frozen in time with the site as it was on the day it was built.  So I added a small Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html
```

And I updated the Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
  environment {
    dockerCredentials = 'omitted'
    dockerRegistryUrl = 'omitted'
    imageName = "our.path.example.com/myproject"
  }
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'node'
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        script {
          sh 'make'
          app = docker.build(imageName, "-f site/Dockerfile site/dist/")
          withDockerRegistry(credentialsId: dockerCredentials, url: dockerRegistryUrl) {
            app.push('latest')
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What happened next was unexpected.  It doesn't like the docker build command.  It says `docker: not found`.  Apparently, the docker command is not installed.

I then attempted to apt/apk install it ran into access denied errors.

```
00:00:01.432  E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
00:00:01.432  E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

Sudo is also not available apparently in that "node" image.  I tried other images as well.  It seems that I am never allowed to install any dependencies into the docker image listed under agent.

I also tried using the scripted pipeline and attempted to install thing and was met with the same issue:

```
stage ('Install') {
    sh 'apt install npm'
}
```

It seems that I cannot install anything.

How can I install the tools I need to build my application?

Comment: [Docker not found when building docker image using Docker Jenkins container pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44850565/docker-not-found-when-building-docker-image-using-docker-jenkins-container-pipel) discusses that error message; do the solutions there work (to install a `docker` binary in the Jenkins container)?

Comment: It doesn't work.  It always says "docker: not found" when it gets to the docker.build line.  Even with adding the tool like that link mentioned.

Comment: This seems that since I need to install something (in this case docker) isn't possible when using the `agent{docker{image 'node'}}` approach.  If I change the image to `any`" or some version of debian/ubuntu/alpine I also cannot install anything.  I get `access denied` errors.  Should I be using a `node{}` rather than a `pipeline{}`?