# 'docker: Exec format error' in Jenkins Docker Pipeline Running on Mac

Tags: macos, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm running Jenkins inside a Docker container on an iMac (Late 2013 - Intel) and trying to use the Docker pipeline. My docker-compose.yml for Jenkins looks like this:

```
version: "3"
  services:
    jenkins:
      container_name: jenkins
      build:
        context: ./jenkins/
      restart: always
      ports:
       - 8080:8080
      volumes:
        - /Users/dev/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home
        - /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
        - /Users/dev/.docker/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

I've given Docker Desktop access to the necessary paths and have followed this tutorial:

https://gist.github.com/afloesch/ea855b30cfb9f157dda8c207d40f05c0

The pipeline's Hello World example provided by Jenkins:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

works just fine, so I know pipelines are working ok in Jenkins, but anything using a Docker image, for example:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'python:3.7.3'
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Do job stage') {
      steps {
        sh "python --version"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Results in the `docker: Exec format error` error:

```
+ docker inspect -f . python:3.7.3
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/canary@tmp/durable-4029f4a8/script.sh: 1: docker: Exec format error
```

Googling has suggested two things. Either adding a shebang to the 'script'. I'm not sure which script is being referred too and adding it to the pipeline script makes no difference:

```
#!/bin/bash
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'python:3.7.3'
    }
  }
...
```

or specifying the platform:

```
jenkins:
    container_name: jenkins
    build:
      context: ./jenkins/
      platform: linux/amd64
  ...
```

But that doesn't work either.

Anyone know what to do?

Comment: You're bind-mounting a MacOS `docker` binary into a Linux container, which is why you're getting the "exec format error" message.  [Docker not found when building docker image using Docker Jenkins container pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44850565/docker-not-found-when-building-docker-image-using-docker-jenkins-container-pipel) discusses a couple of ways to get a `docker` binary in Jenkins, with newer answers advising against bind-mounting the host's binary; does one of those alternatives help?

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze! This, from your link, was what I needed! https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/docker/#downloading-and-running-jenkins-in-docker