# Execute Jenkins steps from Jenkins Docker's container to another Docker's container

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have a microservice architecture made up by several services which lay on Docker containers. In particular I have Jenkins service on a Docker container and a ionic app on another different Docker container.
I want to execute `ionic build` command within Jenkinsfile.
My Jenkinsfile is this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Chekout') {
            steps {
                echo 'Checkout Started'
                git url: <githubrepo>, branch: 'main', credentialsId: 'credentialsId'
                echo 'starting build ionic'
                dir('./frontend') {
                    sh 'ionic build'
                    echo 'ionic build completed'
                }
                echo 'Checkout Completed'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo 'Testing..'
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                echo 'Deploying....'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Right now `ionic build` command is executed on Jenkins container which hasn't ionic installed; for this reason it will fail.
My goal is to execute this build command from Jenkins container to Frontend container.

I read some questions which talk about opening pipes, but this sound quite cumbersome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can start a new Container from the base image which has Ionic and run your command. Is that an option?

Comment: Mh. Yes, it could be. But how can I start the new container within Jenkins? I cannot execute ```docker ...``` inside Jenkins container. It hasn't Docker installed

Comment: Yes, first you need to install docker to the Jenkins Base image or you can add a new agent to the existing Jenkins server with Docker already installed. If you don't want to install Docker, the other option is to enable SSH in the Ionic container so you can remotely execute commands in the running container.

Comment: Jenkins can run individual steps inside (new, temporary) containers; see [Using Docker with Pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) for Groovy pipeline syntax.  On the installation front, also see [Docker not found when building docker image using Docker Jenkins container pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44850565/docker-not-found-when-building-docker-image-using-docker-jenkins-container-pipel).

Comment: None of these proposals seem to work fine. SSH solution works but in production is not a good idea to keep open port 22. I think that the only solution is to install jenkins on machine directly, without docker... to my great regret