# Jenkins and Docker compose: No such file or directory eror when adding a command

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

I have a compose manifest with all my services(client,server,db) and also a jenkins image, in my compose file, it works fine if I add no commands for the Jenkins image (my container runs without issues).

But Since i would like to make use of Docker commands in my Jenkinsfile, I would need Docker installed within my Jenkins container, i tried adding commands to be able to get the Docker client in my container but I get this error

```
/usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh: line 49: /apt-get update && curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh: No such file or directory
```

My Jenkinsfile just consists of commands to output the versions of docker, docker compose etc

This is my docker compose file for jen

```
version: '3.7'

# Define services
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    privileged: true
    user: root
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 50000:50000
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - jenkins-volume:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - docker_certs:/certs/client
    # this is what gives me an error    
    command:
      - "apt-get update && curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | bash"

volumes:
  jenkins-volume:
  docker_certs:
```

If i remove this command

```
    command:
      - "apt-get update && curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | bash"
```

and execute those commands manually via the shell, it works fine and my Jenkins job actually works as expected, but adding this command in my compose file doesn't and gives me an error.

---

### **EDIT**

It seems to work now, I ended up using a separate Dockerfile for Jenkins where I could add commands needed to install docker + docker compose and also add the jenkins that Jenkins creates to the docker group (RUN usermod -aG docker jenkins).

**Jenkins Dockerfile**

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
USER root
# get latest packages
RUN apt-get update
# download docker and docker compose
RUN curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
# add the jenkins user to the docker group - fixed the permissions issue
RUN usermod -aG docker jenkins
```

and in my docker compose file

```
 jenkins:
    privileged: true
    build:
      # Path where my Dockerfile is (Wherever you put the above Dockerfile)
      context: ./
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 50000:50000
    restart: always

    # Making use of the 2 volumes defined in volumes section to persist data after bringing containers down
    volumes:
      - jenkins-volume:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - docker_certs:/certs/client

# you would need to create these volumes first
# using this: docker volume create <your_volume_name>
volumes:
  jenkins-volume:
  docker_certs:
```

I brought down all my containers and then brought it back up, accessed the jenkins url in my browser and I could complete my test pipeline successfully.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
    
        // Makes sure docker and docker compose are on the system
        stage('Verify tools') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                    docker info
                    docker version
                    docker compose version
                    curl --version
                  '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The Compose `command:` runs _instead of_ the normal container process; that's not a great place to install additional packages.  Do you mean to do this in a custom Dockerfile instead?  Is [Docker not found when building docker image using Docker Jenkins container pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44850565/docker-not-found-when-building-docker-image-using-docker-jenkins-container-pipel) your actual problem, and do the setups there help you?

Comment: I've tried creating a seperate Dockerfile to download docker etc and adding that Dockerfile in my compose manifest but now I'm getting a different error

error touch: cannot touch ‘/var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log’: Permission denied