# Unable to mount docker-compose from the host to docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I would like to mount the docker-compose from the host to docker container but it is not working. When I try to execute the **docker-compose** inside the container, I will get the error

> bash: /usr/local/bin/docker-compose: cannot execute: required file not
> found

But the plain **docker** command is working

[image]

Here is my docker-compose.yml,

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    build:
      context: ./
    privileged: true
    user: root
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 50000:50000
    container_name: jenkins-lts
    volumes:
      - ~/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
      - ~/.ssh:/var/jenkins_home/.ssh
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/local/bin/docker
      - /usr/bin/docker-compose:/usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

I do execute the command **'which docker-compose'** on my ubuntu and it shows me

> /usr/bin/docker-compose

Comment: You can't in general bind-mount binaries into a container.  If `docker-compose` is the version 1 Python implementation, for example, there are going to be support files in `/usr/lib/python` or similar that also need to be available.  This seems to be a variant of [Docker not found when building docker image using Docker Jenkins container pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44850565/docker-not-found-when-building-docker-image-using-docker-jenkins-container-pipel) and the answers that suggest adding tools in a Dockerfile (like [this one](/a/44851179)) might work better for you.