# How to edit code in kubernetes pod containers using VS Code?

Tags: kubernetes, visual-studio-code

Typically, if I have a remote server, I could access it using ssh, and VS Code gives a beautiful extension for editing and debugging codes for the remote server. But when I create pods in Kuberneters, I can't really ssh into the container and so I cannot edit the code inside the pod or machine. And the kuberneters plugin in VSCode does not really help because the plugin is used to deploy the code. So, I was wondering whether there is a way edit codes inside a pod using VSCode.

P.S. Alternatively if there is a way to ssh into a pod in a kuberneters, that will do too.

Comment: Kubernetes isn't really designed for this.  Even if you have a "test" or "development" cluster, your workflows need to look more like a production environment: build and test your application code locally; then push it to a Docker registry; then deploy it, and don't try to live-edit code there.  Remember that sometimes Kubernetes will delete a pod on its own, and when this happens all of the data and local edits in the pod will get lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well a pod is just a unit of deployment in kubernetes which means you can tune the containers inside it to receive an ssh connection.

Let's start by getting a docker image that allows ssh connections. `rastasheep/ubuntu-sshd:18.04` image is quite nice for this. Create a deployment with it.

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: debugger
  name: debugger
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: debugger
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: debugger
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: debugger
        image: rastasheep/ubuntu-sshd:18.04
        imagePullPolicy: "Always"
      hostname: debugger
      restartPolicy: Always
```

Now let's create a service of type LoadBalancer such that we can access the pod remotely.

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: debugger
  name: debugger
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: "22"
    port: 22
    targetPort: 22
  selector:
    app: debugger
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Finally, get the external ip address by running `kubectl get svc | grep debugger` and use it to test the ssh connection `ssh root@external_ip_address`

**Note** the user / pass of this docker image is **root / root** respectively.

**UPDATE**
Nodeport example. I tested this and it worked running `ssh -p30036@ip`**BUT** I had to enable a firewall rule to make it work. So, the `nmap` command that I gave you has the answer. Obviously the machines that run kubernetes don't allow inbound traffic on weird ports. Talk to them such that they can give you an external ip address or at least a port in a node.

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: debugger
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: debugger
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: "ssh"
    port: 22
    nodePort: 30036
  selector:
    app: debugger
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Comment: I have tested this myself so if you have any question let me know.

Comment: thank you @Rodrigo! But I am afraid, I am seeing the external IP is in pending state

Comment: Which cloud provider are you using?

Comment: If your LoadBalancer is not working, then you can use a NodePort type service. Change `type: LoadBalancer` to `type: NodePort`. Apply the service. This service type binds the port to the external IP addresses of the nodes. Use `kubectl get nodes -o wide` to obtain those IP addresses. Use any.

Another disadvantage is that port 22 will not be preserved, instead it will be binded to a port in the range 30K to 32K. Use that port instead of 22.

Comment: I see, you will have to look at their documentation to find out how they can give you an external IP address for that service. Since it costs money, they might not give it for free.

Comment: I am trying your Nodeport solution, and I got a lot of external IP addresses. You said use to use any, and I used one of them. But still no luck. Getting this error: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

Comment: which port are you using? Remember nodeport uses a port in the range 30K to 32K

Comment: so I am using 31000, and I am trying to connect by this: ssh -p 31000 root@IP

Comment: Ok, are you sure that is the port assigned?

To check it is not firewall you can run `nmap -p31000 IP_ADDRESS` if it says open, then you should be able to access it.

I tested both solutions on my GKE cluster and they work just in case.

Comment: so, in the pod, I have changed the sshd configuration to change the port from 22 to 31000 but I could not restart the service. When restart the service (service ssh restart) it actually restarts the pod, and the configuration is gone. Don't know if this is creating the problem.

Comment: No, that is not it.

Comment: The kubernetes service will redirect whatever port in the Node IP or LoadBalancer IP to port 22 in the pod.

Comment: Let me show you an example output of a Nodeport. When I run `kubectl get svc | grep NodePort` I get the following. 

default test-deployment NodePort 10.48.14.29 <none> 22:30081/TCP 18d

Comment: Note port 30081 is the one that I should be using to reach port 22 on the pod. Also, check with nmap command if port 310.. is open to external traffic. I believe you have a firewall restriction.

Comment: I am a little bit confused, can you update your current answer for Nodeport, please? I changed both of the port to 31000. I think one of them still should be 22.

Comment: Yes, that is the issue then. You are getting confused about the pod's port.

Answer (score 29):

If your requirement is "kubectl edit xxx" to use VSCode.

The solution is:

- For **Linux,macos**: `export EDITOR='code --wait'`
- For **Windows**: `set EDITOR=code --wait`

Comment: Wow thanks a lot! Especially for the `--wait`. FYI, doing `export EDITOR="code --wait"` works flawlessly on macOS (Catalina 10.15.7).

Comment: Isn't the question about remote editing rather than using vscode for local editing? the answers with using "Kubernetes + Remote Development extensions" is much more relevant.

Comment: Yes, sorry for irrelevant answer :(

Comment: after executing the command, what operation needs to be performed once we edit the file and saved

Comment: @Spartan once you save file and exit vscode process, kubectl will read temp file and execute it.

Answer (score 15):

Kubernetes + Remote Development extensions now allow:

- attaching to k8s pods
- open remote folders
- execute remotely
- debug on remote
- integrated terminal into remote

[image: vscode attaching to k8s pod]

must have:

- kubectl
- docker (minimum = docker cli - [Is it possible to install only the docker cli and not the daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38675925/is-it-possible-to-install-only-the-docker-cli-and-not-the-daemon))

required vscode extentions:

- Kubernetes. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-kubernetes-tools.vscode-kubernetes-tools
- Remote Development - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack

Answer (score 6):

It is actually straightforward but not well documented in the extension.

1. In the kubernetes cluster explorer expand the resource you want to edit. Double clicking on it should open it's yaml in the editor on right, also you could right click on it and select "Load".
2. Make the necessary changes to the file. Don't bother saving as it will error out saying "This command requires an open folder."
3. Ctrl + Shift + P (Windows), choose command: Kubernetes: Apply
4. It will show you the diff, prompt you to confirm to apply
5. Magic!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in some of the other answers, you can do this although it is fraught with danger as the cluster can/will replace pods regularly and when it does, it starts a new pod idempotently from the configuration which will not have your changes.

The command below will get you a shell session in your pod , which can sometimes be helpful for debugging if you don't have adequate monitoring/local testing facilities to recreate an issue.

```
kubectl --namespace=exmaple exec -it my-cool-pod-here -- /bin/bash
```

Note You can replace the command with any tool that is installed in your container (python3, sh, bash, etc). Also know that that some base images like alpine wont have bash/shell installed be default.

This will open a bash session in the running container on the cluster, assuming you have the correct k8s RBAC permissions.

Answer (score 0):

There is an  [Cloud Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GoogleCloudTools.cloudcode&ssr=false#overviewthat) available for VS Code that will serve your purpose.

You can install it in your Visual Studio Code to interact with your Kubernetes cluster.

It allows you to create minikube cluster, Google GKE, Amazon EKS or Azure AKS and manage it from VS Code (you can access cluster information, stream/view logs from pods and open interactive terminal to the container).
You can also enable continuous deployment so it will continuously watch for changes in your files, rebuild the container and redeploy application to the cluster.

It is well explained in [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/vscode/how-to)

Hope it will be useful for your use case.