# Changes not applying in kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have attached to a running pod using vscode using the remote development extension, like described in a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58601318/is-there-a-way-to-edit-codes-in-kubernetes-pods-using-vs-code).

However, the changes are not applied to the running pod. I have `kubectl exec <pod-name> -it -- /bin/sh` in the pod and see that the file is changed. Does the pod need to get restarted for changes to apply or is there some cache I am missing? I am a beginner in kubernetes.

Comment: Pods are ephemeral...the remote developer extension in this case is more suitable to debugging than actually coding changes into a pod. You need to follow this workflow, changes in my project -> docker build, docker run to check changes are ok, docker push with new tag and just update the deployment with the new image tag

Comment: Yes for permanent changes your proposed way is the way to go. But I wanted to test some changes in the running cluster before creating a whole new image. In principle changes, through this approach should still directly have effect or, or am I missing something fundamental?

Comment: Maybe if you attach a volume to the pod and in that volume is also you code, then it should be able to refresh the code at the pod level.

Comment: The code is `python` and the pod is using `celery` that is taking calls from a `django` platform to trigger python tasks. Can it be that it is not a kubernetes issue but something in this stack caches the python code?